# P2 self provisioning RCP vs. Windows UAC

Tags: windows, eclipse, uac, p2

We used to savor the joy that is a self updating Eclipse RCP application on Windows XP (it´s an company only internal document management system). Now after switching to Windows7 updates will only be performed if the application is run as an Administrator which of course erases the joy out of the thing that is a self updating application.

The self provisioning is more or less copy/paste from this [article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application#Headless_Updating_on_Startup)

Since the installation folder is bound to C:\Program Files (company policies...) the application may no longer write to this folder, unless started as an elevated process. What p2 does (at least I think after an epic debugging session) is to download artifact.xml and content.xml from the p2 repository to compare locally and build an update plan. Unfortunately if it is not able to store the downloaded files it simply says "Nothing to update".

I already tried to give the shared installation/bundlepool a try, in which the bundles are installed to the user directory using the p2 director application with the following properties:

```
-metadataRepository http://someserver/updatesite
-artifactRepository http://someserver/updatesite
-installIUs my.application.id
-roaming
-destination "C:\Program Files\MyApplication"
-bundlepool C:\Users\me\MyApplication
-profile DefaultProfile
-profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true
-p2.os win32
-p2.ws win32
-p2.arch x86_64

-Declipse.p2.data.area=C:\Users\me\.p2
```

The installer works kind of well and the application may start (after telling her, that the launcher is in my user directory). But unfortunately the self provisiong still doesn´t work this way. Run as administrator will result in downloaded updated bundles and features in the -destination location instead of the -bundlepool location - which is what I expected.

What switch did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

We've had a similar problem here. One of the reasons may be that the IUs being installed still try to write something in the "C:\Program Files\MyApplication" via the p2.inf touchpoint instructions. The solution was to deploy a minimalistic launcher "C:\Program Files\MyApplicationLauncher" which:

1. performs bundle pool updates (dir = "C:\ProgramData\MyBundlePool")
2. and actually installs and launches the application in the %tmp% (dir = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\MyApplication")

Comment: Interesting point. The p2.inf contains instructions to add the P2 repositories to the settings and hence obviously touches the files in the program files directory - even if, as I would expect, touch the files in the directory specified by the p2.data.area property. But what does the ApplicationLauncher do? Check the updates manually? And wouldn´t it run into the same problems as the application did before (try to download files from a repository to a folder where it das no write access)?

Comment: No, the launcher is configured in the way that it operates only with writable directories, which are normally: %tmp% | %appdata% | %allusersprofile% | %userprofile% (Win7)